# Reverse sort array with rearranging of index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So currently I'm having a problem where I have an array setup like this

```
array(8) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.1166666666667) 
        [1]=> string(7) "9434493" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.07) 
        [1]=> string(7) "8591971" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0566666666667) 
        [1]=> string(8) "17015102" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0366666666667) 
        [1]=> string(7) "9637191" 
    } 
    [4]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.015) 
        [1]=> string(8) "11405473" 
    } 
    [5]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(1.9833333333333) 
        [1]=> string(8) "28233403" 
    } 
    [6]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0366666666667) 
        [1]=> string(8) "14248330" 
    } 
    [7]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0933333333333) 
        [1]=> string(8) "14987165" 
    } 
}
```

After I use the function `arsort()` it looks like this:

```
array(8) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.1166666666667) 
        [1]=> string(7) "9434493" 
    } 
    [7]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0933333333333) 
        [1]=> string(8) "14987165" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.07) 
        [1]=> string(7) "8591971" 
    } 
    [2]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0566666666667) 
        [1]=> string(8) "17015102" 
    } 
    [6]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0366666666667) 
        [1]=> string(8) "14248330" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.0366666666667) 
        [1]=> string(7) "9637191" 
    } 
    [4]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(2.015) 
        [1]=> string(8) "11405473" 
    } 
    [5]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> float(1.9833333333333) 
        [1]=> string(8) "28233403" 
    } 
}
```

So all cool that my array is sorted by the value of [0] index. But.....

When I try to loop through like this...

```
$x = 0;
while ($x < count($sorted_array)) {
    $sorted_array[$x][0];
    $x++;
}
```

It kept printing out the original array order. I then realized when I used the function `arsort()` it kept the original order of the indexes so that's why it was printing in the original array order.

Is there a function to fix this so I can loop it with an index? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `foreach()` loop

Comment: Use `rsort` function instead of `arsort`, if you don't want to keep index position with value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `arsort()` you preserve the keys.

Because you are iterating using `$x`, you are effectively ignoring your sort call.

Either use `rsort()` with your loop.

Or use a `foreach()` loop after your `arsort()` call.

Or best, just call `array_column()` instead of looping.

Here are some demonstrations: ([Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/NRLF0))

```
$array=$copy=[
    [2.1166666666667,9434493],
    [2.07,8591971],
    [2.0566666666667,17015102],
    [2.0366666666667,9637191],
    [2.015,11405473],
    [1.9833333333333,28233403],
    [2.0366666666667,14248330],
    [2.0933333333333,14987165]
];
arsort($array);
var_export(array_column($array,0));  // <-- you lose the keys you preserved
echo "\n---\n";

foreach($array as $index=>$row){     // <-- you keep the keys you preserved
    echo "$index : {$row[0]}\n";
}

echo "\n---\n";
rsort($copy);                        // you don't preserve the keys
for($x=0, $count=sizeof($copy); $x<$count; ++$x){  // you should cache the count instead of calling count() on every iteration
    echo "$x : {$copy[$x][0]}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 2.1166666666667,
  1 => 2.0933333333333,
  2 => 2.07,
  3 => 2.0566666666667,
  4 => 2.0366666666667,
  5 => 2.0366666666667,
  6 => 2.015,
  7 => 1.9833333333333,
)
---
0 : 2.1166666666667
7 : 2.0933333333333
1 : 2.07
2 : 2.0566666666667
6 : 2.0366666666667
3 : 2.0366666666667
4 : 2.015
5 : 1.9833333333333

---
0 : 2.1166666666667
1 : 2.0933333333333
2 : 2.07
3 : 2.0566666666667
4 : 2.0366666666667
5 : 2.0366666666667
6 : 2.015
7 : 1.9833333333333
```

Comment: I will use one of these methods. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

[`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) is great fit here.

> Sort an array in reverse order

This function does not maintain index association

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at PHP documentation suggests `rsort()` would work.

http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php